# when new dropdown filter is chosen, selected lines in chart don't remain consistent

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working on a line chart with some filters. It works the way I want on the first load, but when I change the dropdown selection, things break.

I'd like the selected states to remain selected as the dropdown selection changes. Right now if you de-select Maine, while on the 'apples' dropdown, then switch to the 'pears' dropdown, the Maine line comes back (though the select box remains gray.)

How can I maintain the selected lines?

[Here is a plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/HN8XHjP0caHJ1gUYs2ZX?p=preview)

And the code is below, too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path {
    stroke: #ccc;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
#legendContainer{
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
    left:10px;
    overflow: auto;
    height:490px;
    width:110px;
}
#legend{
    width:90px;
    height:200px;
}
.legend {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-anchor: left;
}
.legendcheckbox{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#showAll{
    position:absolute;
    top:600px;
    left:880px;
}
#clearAll{
    position:absolute;
    top:600px;
    left:950px;
}
input{
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#999;
    border:0;
    color:#fff;
}
#inds{
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library -->
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<select id="inds">
        <option value="apples" selected="selected">apples</option>
        <option value="pears">pears</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">tomatoes</option>
</select>
<div id="legendContainer" class="legendContainer">
    <svg id="legend"></svg>
</div>
<div id="showAll">
    <input name="showAllButton"
     type="button"
     value="Show All"
     onclick="showAll()" />
</div>
<div id="clearAll">
    <input name="clearAllButton"
     type="button"
     value="Clear All"
     onclick="clearAll()" />
</div>
<script>

function filterJSON(json, key, value) {
  var result = [];
  for (var produce in json) {
    if (json[produce][key] === value) {
      result.push(json[produce]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 160},
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 550 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var stateline = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
              "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var data;
// Get the data
d3.json("data.json", function(error, json) {
  console.log("json", json);

  json.forEach(function(d) {
        d.value = +d.value;
  });

    d3.select('#inds')
            .on("change", function () {
                var sect = document.getElementById("inds");
                var section = sect.options[sect.selectedIndex].value;


                data = filterJSON(json, 'produce', section);
                updateGraph(data);


                jQuery('h1.page-header').html(section);
            });

            // generate initial graph
            data = filterJSON(json, 'produce', 'apples');
            updateGraph(data);

});

var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#48A36D",  "#0096ff", "#ff007e"]);

function updateGraph(data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.value = +d.value;
            d.year = parseDate(String(d.year));
            d.active = true;
        });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }));
    y.domain([d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

    // Nest the entries by state
    dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) {return d.state;})
        .entries(data);

        var state = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(dataNest);

        state.enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "line");

        state.transition()
            .style("stroke", function(d,i) { return d.color = color(d.key); })
            .attr("id", function(d){ return 'tag'+d.key.replace(/\s+/g, '');}) // assign ID
            .attr("d", function(d){
                if (d.active = true){return stateline(d.values) }
                else{ return null;}
            });

        state.exit().remove();

        var legend = d3.select("#legend")
            .selectAll("text")
            .data(dataNest);

        //checkboxes
        legend.enter().append("rect")
          .attr("width", 10)
          .attr("height", 10)
          .attr("x", 0)
          .attr("y", function (d, i) { return 0 +i*15; })  // spacing
          .attr("fill",function(d) { if (d.active == true){ return color(d.key);} else {return "#ccc";}})
          .attr("class", "legendcheckbox")
            .on("click", function(d){
                d.active = !d.active;
                // Hide or show the lines based on the ID
                d3.select("#tag"+d.key)
                            .transition().duration(100)
                            .attr("d", function(d){
                if (d.active == true){return stateline(d.values);} else {return null;}
                          });
                        // fill checkbox color or not
                        d3.select(this).attr("fill",function(d) {
                            if (d.active == true){ return color(d.key);}
                            else {return "#ccc";}});
                });
    // Add the Legend text
    legend.enter().append("text")
      .attr("x", 15)
      .attr("y", function(d,i){return 10 +i*15;})
      .attr("class", "legend");

        legend.transition()
      .style("fill", "#777" )
      .text(function(d){return d.key;});

        legend.exit().remove();

        svg.selectAll(".axis").remove();

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);
};

function clearAll(){
  d3.selectAll(".line")
    .transition().duration(100)
            .attr("d", function(d){
        return null;
      });
  d3.select("#legend").selectAll("rect")
  .transition().duration(100)
      .attr("fill", "#ccc");
};

function showAll(){
  d3.selectAll(".line")
    .transition().duration(100)
            .attr("d", function(d){
        return stateline(d.values);
      });
  d3.select("#legend").selectAll("rect")
  .attr("fill",function(d) {
    if (d.active == true){
       return color(d.key);
     }
   })
};

</script>
</body>
```

This is the data.json file:

```
[
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"131"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"231"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"191"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"302"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"31"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"331"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"291"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"250"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"11"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"230"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"185"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"apples",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"310"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"171"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"121"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"231"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"202"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"73"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"151"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"399"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"140"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"146"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"130"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"195"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"pears",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"210"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"71"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"221"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"31"
},
{
  "state":"Maine",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"102"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"173"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"194"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"195"
},
{
  "state":"Pennsylvania",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"230"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":1900,
  "value":"216"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":1950,
  "value":"184"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":2000,
  "value":"125"
},
{
  "state":"Ohio",
  "produce":"tomatoes",
  "year":2015,
  "value":"150"
}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated working Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1BJZgpwPUXnEanVClgK?p=preview)

1. The `dataNest` used to draw lines always contain three elements in the array:

   dataNest = d3.nest()
       .key(function(d) {return d.state;})
       .entries(data);

The `data` from `filterJSON` function includes 3 states for one specific produce. That's why there are three lines on the chart even if the legend selector is togggled. Therefore what needs to be done is to make sure the data you use for generating the paths is matching with not only the produce , but also the states(legend selector), something like:

```
var result = dataNest.filter(function(val,idx, arr){
  return $("." + val.key).attr("fill") !== "#ccc" 
  // matching the data with selector status
})
var state = svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(result, function(d){return d.key});
```

Meanwhile, update the legend selector like this:

```
.attr("class", function(d,i){
        return "legendcheckbox " + d.key
      })
```

So that the data for path is matching with selected legends.

2. Bind the line element with data by key function, so that when you click on the legend selector, it will find corresponding elements. For example:

   var state = svg.selectAll(".line")
     .data(result, function(d){return d.key});

Here, we bind the DOM elements with data by each `key`, specifically the states.

3. There is one step of processing year data for each update:

   data.forEach(function(d) {
       d.value = +d.value;
       d.year = parseDate(String(d.year));
       d.active = true;
   });

If we use the data binding method to handle the existence of one specific line, we should be careful because `d.year` might be processed already, which will lead to `d.year` is `null`. As for showing a standard format on the axis, I think a much safer way is to set the format in xAxis:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
.orient("bottom").ticks(5)
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"))
```

In this way, you don't need to worry about changing the original data, and you can have the time format displayed as you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I think I see what you mean, but I'm not sure. It seems like the new var result is returning an array of 3 objects each time, regardless of what states I uncheck. Here is the [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FqdcAg2kb69WMPNVpimp?p=preview). Any thoughts?

Comment: I forgot to add this in the answer, while appending legends:`.attr("class", function(d,i){return "legendcheckbox " + d.key})`, or add class name if you want, the purpose is to make sure the data for path is matching with the legend selector

Comment: Aha. I have it working now with that addition. Great! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @sprucegoose I updated with a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1BJZgpwPUXnEanVClgK?p=preview). Answer updated as well.

Comment: This is extremely helpful. Thank you again for such a thorough explanation!